# I'm a 17 year old boy who has been described as a Tenor, but somehow I feel like my voice hit a brick wall

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, voice-change

First of all I have no idea how to warm up because somehow it feels pointless. second is that one day I would sing high and a few days or a week later it would seem like my voice is struggling to reach the same height.

I've been feeling this way for years. I've been singing since I was 4 years old but I was ignorant of what it means to be a singer. As a matter of fact I had no idea about the world, that singing can be a profession and that you need proper technique.

Back then I was very shy to the point of feeling like I couldn't breathe. In my spare time when I was alone I would sing at my highest and I would sound a little feminine, but now I don't really know where is my highest.

I often characterize my voice as a road, at the ending of that road is not a barricade it's a collapsed bridge. Sorry for all the intro but my question is, how do I get to the other side of that bridge or how do I release my voice to go higher and extend my vocal range?

Answer (score 3):

There are so many things that you can do wrong as a singer. Only a qualified vocal teacher listening to you physically will be able to tell you exactly what you are doing wrong, and how to work on your problems. You need to take some lessons.